# If there is a periodic solution then every solution is periodic with the same period.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Let $A$ be a $2\times 2 $ real matrix. Suppose the ordinary differential equation
$$x'=Ax$$
has a periodic nonconstant solution $\varphi(t,x_0)$ such that $\varphi(0,x_0)=x_0$ for some $x_0 \neq (0,0),$ i.e., there exists $\tau >0$ such that $\varphi(t+\tau,x_0)=\varphi(t,x_0)$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}.$

Prove that for every initial value $x \neq(0,0)$ we have that the solution $\varphi(t,x)$ is periodic with period $\tau$.

I think I can solve it by separating in 3 cases:

1. $A$ is similar to $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2\end{bmatrix}$, where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. In that case, the solution will be constant, or it will go to infinity or 0. That is, it is not periodic.
2. $A$ is similar to $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda\end{bmatrix}$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is the eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity 2. Similarly, the solution will be constant, or it will go to infinity or 0 depending on the sign of $\lambda$.
3. $A$ is similar to $\begin{bmatrix}a & -b \\ b & a\end{bmatrix}$, where $a\pm bi$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. Then we would conclude that the only way to get periodic solutions is with $a=0$ and $b\neq 0$. And then we see that in this case all the solutions in fact will be periodic with the same period.

I have two questions. Is that solution correct? Is there a cleaner or simpler solution?

Comment: You are correct. Also you can show it in a different way by considering the characteristic polynomial of the matrix.

Comment: @SahanManodya Can you say a bit more on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$, the differential equation has periodic solutions when the eigen-values of $A$ are purely imaginery, i.e. eigen values are $i\omega$ and $-i\omega$ for some $\omega>0$. Then the general solution is,
$$x(t)=ae^{i\omega t}+be^{-i\omega t}$$
for some $a\in E(i\omega)$ and $b\in E(-i\omega)$. Here $E$ denotes the eigenspace if each eigen-vector.

Now define $T=2\pi/\omega$. Then it's clear that  $e^{i\omega(t+T)}=e^{i\omega t}$ and $e^{-i\omega(t+T)}=e^{i\omega t}$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore the general solution is periodic and therefore every solution is perioic whenever the eigen-values are purely imaginary.

Comment: How would you prove that the differential equation has periodic solutions when the eigen-values are purely imaginary? Would it be necessary a case analysis as I did? Is there a clean way to show that if $A$ has an eigenvalue with real part different from zero than the solution is not periodic?